# Asymptotic limit of a summation

Tags: probability, limits, analysis, asymptotics

I am calculating a bound for a random variable. Using the Chernoff bound, I get to the following:
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} n^{ -2s\big[ \frac{\log(s)-1}{\log (n)} \pm 2 o_n(1) \big]}
$$
Can someone help me to find the asymptotic behavior of the sum?

P.S.: $o_n(1)$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Riemann sum perhaps?

Comment: It simplifis to $$
\sum\limits_{s = 1}^{n/2} {\left( {\frac{{\rm e}}{s}} \right)^{2s} n^{ \mp s \cdot o_n (1)} } .
$$